# Guice bind().toInstance() injects already injected members?

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

I have multiple injectors in a multi module project, and want to pass an already injected instance from module A to another Guice module B:

```
//module B    
bind(DeleteEmployeeUseCaseFactory.class).toInstance(useCaseFactories);
//usecaseFactories comes from module A, and already injected
```

However this results binding exception in module B as guice tries to re-inject "usecaseFactories" members in moduleB where those dependencies not binded.

**Why guice try to inject given instance's members, and how to avoid that?**

Comment: Can you post more about the exception? Though it's rare to manage multiple injectors manually (compared to creating child injectors), I don't see a reason that what you described shouldn't work. Just remember that modules and injectors are different things, and Guice doesn't care about module dependencies, it cares about injector dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is exactly same as described here: https://github.com/google/guice/issues/751. Modules are separated because they encapsulating their inside DI behavior, just communicating through an interface (useCaseFactories in this case). Maybe not the best design, but I don't have an example to make it with child injector while keeping modules independent and clean.

Comment: However I solved my problem with Providers.of(..).

Comment: Sounds like an excellent solution! I learned something new. You may want to link to the big and Auto Injection wiki page as a self-answer.

Answer (score 3):

I solved to avoid injection of instance's already injected members by using Provider:

```
bind(DeleteEmployeeUseCaseFactory.class).toProvider(Providers.of(useCaseFactories));
```

However this is guice's expected behavior as decribed [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#automatic-injection):

#### Automatic Injection

Guice automatically injects all of the following:

- instances passed to `toInstance()` in a bind statement
- provider instances passed to `toProvider()` in a bind statement
  The objects will be injected while the injector itself is being created. If they're needed to satisfy other startup injections, Guice will inject them before they're used.